# Find if url query "id" is equal to tab-1

Tags: php, url

This is what I have for my code.

```
$query = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($query) == tab-1) {
    echo $query;
}else{
    echo "nope";
}
```

The above code is checking if my url has /?id but it isn't checking if the ?id is equal to tab-1.

It returns true even if my url is /?id=tab-2 and $query is equal to tab-2.

Comment: `isset` returns a boolean. Also syntax errors.

Comment: `"tab-1"` apply this type

Comment: Also, you'll get an undefined constant error here, `... == tab-1) {`

Comment: Why the negative votes? It's very unhelpful to downvote a question with no feedback how am I to ever improve my question asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $query = $_GET['id'];

    if($query == "tab-1") {
       echo $query;
    } else {
       echo "nope";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for I didn't realize I needed the extra if else statement.

Comment: I did not understand your comments

Answer (score 0):

```js
<?php
$query = $_GET['id'];

if($query == "tab-1") {
    echo $query;
}else{
    echo "nope";
}
?>
```